# SAP BI RESTful services don't work with basic authentication

Tags: rest, basic-authentication, business-objects, business-objects-sdk, sap-bw

I'm trying to call the SAP BI/BO RESTful webservices using basic authentication. I enabled basic authentication in the WACS and tested with this service:

```
http://host:6405/infostore/16422
```

This works! I can get the report metadata as either XML or JSON. However, whenever I try an URL with "raylight" in it, I get an authentication problem:

```
http://host:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/16422/parameters

{
error_code: "1"
message: "No session found in HTTP header X-SAP-LogonToken"
}
```

Why do some services work with basic authentication and others absolutely require the logontoken?

I would like to avoid the logontoken if possible. I tested by logging on with the token and that does work, so it's not like my credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you asked the same question on [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3730090) which was answered by one of the SAP developers, Anthony Muller.

He stated that:

> Raylight doesn't support basic authentication because it required a
>   permanent session to work. Internally, we have to manage a "cache" to
>   support subsequent REST calls and this is not possible using basic
>   authentication.